# Enable type information in editor in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I checked a video where someone is using Intellij Idea and all the time his editor is showing this bar with info of the variable he is editing:

[image]

How can I enable this to IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Breadcrumbs | Show breadcrumbs: ☑.

- Placement: Top.
- Java: ☑.